# How do I rotate my HighCharts bar chart so its vertical, not horizontal?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'QueryResultsChart',
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Production History'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Production Day'
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Gross Production'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Data',
        data: []
    }]
});
chart1.series[0].setData(". json_encode($aChartData) .");
});
```

The data is there an correct, it's just showing my xAxis on the yAxis for some reason...

Comment: Cool I want a rotated chart as well!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Vertical bar charts are called `column`'s in Highchart.

Change this:

```
type: 'column' //was 'bar' previously`
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aznBb/

Answer (score 21):

To expand on Moin Zaman's answer, I played with his jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aznBb/ and found this.

This is **horizontal**.

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    inverted: false // default
}
```

This is **also horizontal**.

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    inverted: true
}
```

This is **vertical**.

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: false // default
}
```

This is **horizontal** and apparently **identical to the bar charts**.

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true
}
```

Very odd. I can only guess that `type: 'bar'` aliases `type: 'column'` and forces `inverted: true` no matter what it's actually set at. It'd be nice if it just toggled the `inverted` boolean.

Comment: Do you know if the title can be inverted?

Comment: Here's the API for title: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title

I'm no HighCharts expert, but I'd assume the setting would be there (and it seems to not be an option).

However, you can move it around a bit if that suits your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/title/verticalalign/

Comment: This also applies for other chart types such as boxplot.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
$(function () {

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Temperature variation by month'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Observed in Vik i Sogn, Norway'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature ( °C )'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y + '°C';
                }
            }
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperatures',
        data: [
            [-9.7, 9.4],
            [-8.7, 6.5],
            [-3.5, 9.4],
            [-1.4, 19.9],
            [0.0, 22.6],
            [2.9, 29.5],
            [9.2, 30.7],
            [7.3, 26.5],
            [4.4, 18.0],
            [-3.1, 11.4],
            [-5.2, 10.4],
            [-13.5, 9.8]
        ]
    }]

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/b940oyw4/